# Armazenar var_dump em uma variavel

Tags: php, var-dump

Preciso mostrar a *array* e armazena-la em uma variável, as funções que eu conheço que fazem isso sao `var_dump` e `print_r`, porem eles nao armazenam na *string*, eles ja dao `echo`.

Qual função usar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função correta é o [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) pois a mesma aceita um segundo parâmetro para passar a saída ao invés de fazer o *dump* da mesma:

Exemplo:

```
$b = array ('m' => 'monkey', 'foo' => 'bar', 'x' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
$results = print_r($b, true);
```

Saída para a variável `$results`:

```
Array
(
    [m] => monkey
    [foo] => bar
    [x] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )

)
```

A variável `$results` vai tornar-se uma *string* com o conteúdo em cima apresentado.

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/SwFdS8).

Comment: Urei sua funcao e deu tudo ok `$results = is_array($execute) ? print_r($execute, true) : $execute;
` porem ao enviar o $results por websockets ele desconecta D:

Comment: Isso é outro problema completamente diferente e não endereçado na tua pergunta inicial. Abre uma pergunta sobre o problema de enviar o resultado do `print_r($arr, true)` por _websockets_ de forma a que te possamos ajudar.

Comment: Resolvi usar json para enviar, mais pratico. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar `$string = var_export($array, true);` para guardar uma string do array